# How do I get the widths of the borders drawn by ControlPaint?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm drawing a border with System.Windows.ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D, and want to draw into the rectangle inside the border.  How do I get the width of the border, so that I can find the rectangle inside it?

UPDATE: With the default theme, the borders are 2px top and left, but only 1px bottom and right, so SystemInformation.Border3DSize isn't quite sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

may this two "friends" help you?

- SystemInformation.Border3DSize.Height
- SystemInformation.Border3DSize.Width